# Hexdigest in Python

Tags: python-2.7, md5

How the Hexdigest md5 values of two same CSV files are different when I check it. The difference between the two CSV files is that one is tab seperated and the other one is comma seperated, else the values are same.

```
f1 = open(r'D:\Temporary\New File.csv',mode='r')
f2 = open(r'D:\Temporary\Old File.csv',mode='r')
print hashlib.md5(t1).hexdigest(),'    ',hashlib.md5(t2).hexdigest()
if hashlib.md5(t1).hexdigest()== hashlib.md5(t2).hexdigest():
    print "Match"
else:
    print "Not Match"
```

The output shows :

```
a4b2720cafdcb859e7ef07a7a3564ba3      237a5c28b890f94636035482a363853a
Not Match
```

On the other hand, this code gives correct output, where I introduced read() function and then took the md5 digest. Now the keys **match**.

```
f1 = open(r'D:\Temporary\New File.csv',mode='r')
f2 = open(r'D:\Temporary\Old File.csv',mode='r')
print f1.read()
print f2.read()
print hashlib.md5(t1).hexdigest(),'    ',hashlib.md5(t2).hexdigest()
if hashlib.md5(t1).hexdigest()== hashlib.md5(t2).hexdigest():
    print "Match"
else:
    print "Not Match"
```

Now, the output is:

```
Ultimator Start Code Start Count    
Ultimator,Start Code,Start Count,,,,
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e      d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
Match
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is a cryptographic hash function, which works on the raw data of a file. If two CSV files have the same contents (by your consideration) just using different delimiters, the raw data differs. That's why the MD5 hexdigest values must differ too.

When you call `file.read` before, the position pointer of this file will be at the end of the file and calling `file.read` again after returns `''`:

```
>>> hashlib.md5('').hexdigest()
'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
```

Comment: I used split() to separate the commas(,) and tabs(\t) from the contents and after that it worked nicely.